# Using regular expression to extract all cookie attribute

Tags: c#, regex, f#

For example, if I have a cookie string

```
"lu=Rg3vHJ; Expires=Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.example.com; HttpOnly"
```

How to extract all the cookie attributes in the following list:

```
NameValuePair // Mandatory "lu" and "Rg3vHJ"
Domain // ".example.com"
Path // "/"
Expires // "Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT"
MaxAge // Not exist in the example
Secure // Not exist
HttpOnly // Exists
```

Not sure if the order of the attributes in the `Set-Cookie" is fixed. How do I write the expression if it can be in any order and missing (all other attributes may be missing except the main name/value pair)?

I will need to assign the values to either a C# struct or F# record.

```
struct { 
    KeyValuePair<string, string> NameValue, // mandatory 
    string Domain,
    string Path,
    string Expires,
    string MaxAge,
    bool Secure,
    bool HttpOnly
}
```

F#

```
type Cookie = {
    NameValue : string * string;
    Domain : string option;
    Path : string option;
    Expires : string option;
    MaxAge : string;
    Secure : bool; // ? no associated value, anything better than bool
    HttpOnly : bool; // ? no associated value, anything better than bool
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why particularly a regex? Split it on `;` and then each token on `=` to get each key-value pair.

Comment: I had `(.+?)(?:=(.+?))?(?:;|$|,(?!\s))` but I want to match the attributes explicitly. However, the order of the attributes may change.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'm trying to avoid a bunch of `if`s before assign the values to a struct (c#) or record (F#).

Comment: This is very close to a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197563/

Comment: @JohnPalmer This question is more about regular expression. That one is more about F#.

Comment: At least, you could have posted a compilable code. Too busy to post a good question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string cookie = "lu=Rg3vHJ; Expires=Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.example.com; HttpOnly";
var parts = cookie.Split(';')
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x.Length > 1 ? x[1].Trim() : "");

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, parts.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value)));
```

or using your regex posted in comments

```
var pattern = @"(.+?)(?:=(.+?))?(?:;|$|,(?!\s))";

var parts = Regex.Matches(cookie, pattern).Cast<Match>()
                 .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change cookie to `class` because I'm going to use it within LINQ. I also change `NameValue` to dictionary (to store all not matched properties):

```
class Cookie { 
    public Dictionary<string, string> NameValue; // mandatory 
    public string Domain;
    public string Path;
    public string Expires;
    public string MaxAge;
    public bool Secure;
    public bool HttpOnly;
}
```

Then combine using Reflection and LINQ to fill named properties and everything else into dictionary:

```
Cookie c = new Cookie();
c.NameValue = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Regex.Matches(cookie, @"(\w+)=?([^;]*)")
                .OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
                .Select(m => new 
                {
                    Key = m.Groups[1].Value,
                    Value = m.Groups.Count > 2 ? m.Groups[2].Value : null,
                    Field = typeof(Cookie).GetField(m.Groups[1].Value)
                })
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x =>
                {
                    if (x.Field != null)
                        x.Field.SetValue(c, 
                                    x.Field.FieldType != typeof(bool) ?
                                    (object)x.Value : true
                                    );
                    else
                        c.NameValue.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
                });
```